# User not logged in using Jwt with Microsoft Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, bearer-token, jwt

Maybe I'm struggling over a really simple thing, I say there are many similar questions around but I'm on this task since some hours and I can't find a way out.

I have a `.net core` backend with `Microsoft.Identity` and `JWT bearer authentication`.

Actually I succesfully get my bearer token to the front-end (angular) on login and Bearer header back to the backend when performing other calls.

Even if that, my `User.Identity` *is not authenticated* in my controller and I can't get my logged user in my controllers.

In my startup.cs OnMessageReceived event the context.token is populated correctly I think, but I can't get the user info back in the controller

What am I doing wrong?

Those are my configurations:

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(o =>
            {
                  o.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
                #if DEBUG
                  o.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
                #else
                  o.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = false;
                #endif
            });

        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy(_cors, builder =>
        {
            builder
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        }));


        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
                (options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        var jwtBearerProvider = new JwtBearerProvider(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:SecretKey"]));
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        context.Token ??= context.Request.Headers
                            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Equals("Authorization"))
                            .Value.ToString(); // Dunno if this has any sense
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = jwtBearerProvider.ValidationParameters;
            });

        services.AddAuthorization(o =>
        {
            o.AddPolicy(AuthPolicies.AdminOnly, builder => builder.RequireRole(Roles.Admin));
        });

        services.AddSingleton(jwtBearerProvider);

        services.AddScoped<ApplicationUsersService>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, AppClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
            rewriteOptions.AddRedirectToWwwPermanent();
        }

        app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);

        var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
        provider.Mappings[".webmanifest"] = "application/manifest+json";

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            ContentTypeProvider = provider
        });

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(_cors);

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(e =>
        {
            e.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            e.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

**JwtBearerProvider.cs**

```
public class JwtBearerProvider
{
    private readonly byte[] _signKey;

    public readonly TokenValidationParameters ValidationParameters;

    public JwtBearerProvider(byte[] signKey)
    {
        _signKey = signKey;
        ValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(_signKey),
            ValidIssuer = Claims.Issuer,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            AuthenticationType = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        };
    }

    public string? CreateToken(IPrincipal? principal)
        => CreateToken(principal?.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

    public string? CreateToken(ApplicationUser? user, string organizationId)
    {
        if (user == null) return null;

        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Id))
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id));
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.UserName))
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
        return CreateToken(identity);
    }


    public string? CreateToken(ClaimsIdentity? identity)
    {
        if (identity == null || _signKey == null || !_signKey.Any())
            return null;

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = identity,
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            Issuer = Claims.Issuer,
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(_signKey),
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };

        return tokenHandler.CreateEncodedJwt(tokenDescriptor);
    }

    public SecurityToken VerifyToken(string token)
    {
        new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(token, ValidationParameters, out var securityToken);
        return securityToken;
    }

    public bool IsTokenValid(string token, ApplicationUser user)
        => IsTokenValid(token, user.UserName);

    public bool IsTokenValid(string token, IIdentity identity)
        => IsTokenValid(token, identity.Name);

    public bool IsTokenValid(string token, string? name)
    {
        var result =
            new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(token, ValidationParameters, out var securityToken);

        return
            result.Identity.IsAuthenticated &&
            result.Identity.Name == name &&
            securityToken.Issuer == ValidationParameters.ValidIssuer &&
            securityToken.SigningKey == ValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey;
    }
}
```

Finally, my controller.cs

```
[ApiController]
[Route(ApiPrefix.V1)]
public class TestController: BaseController
{
    public TestController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet("logged")]
    public IActionResult AmILogged()
    {
        if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated()){
          return Ok("Authenticated :)");
        }
        return Ok("Not authenticated :(");
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, I solved removing the JwtBearerEvents.OnMessageReceived method. If anyone could explain me why this was causing the problem, I would appreciate and mark as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your method and it can get the authenticated user if you send the token bearer to the logged endpoint, either you can pass the user Id inside token claims like this:

[image: User ID to token claims]

Calling your logged endpoint passing the token:
[image: Endpoint Call]

Finally if you want to get the user Id use this:

var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

Hope it helps, regards.

**EDIT:**
This is my JWT configuration

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        // Configuracion bearer  
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:VAudience"],
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:VIssuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
            };
        });
```

To generate my token I use this, the code below returns the token string:

```
 // METODO QUE GENERA JWT TOKEN
    private  string GenerateToken(IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
    {
        
        var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JWT:Secret"]));

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: configuration["JWT:VIssuer"],
            audience: configuration["JWT:VAudience"],
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```

I would also recommend you to read this documentation about JWT Token authentication and authorization in .NET CORE:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core-web-api-with-json-web-tokens/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your reply. I tried this but it's not working. In my controller I still get User.findfirst(..) = null. Maybe I'm doing something wrong in the startup.cs file? In your working example, how was your jwt configuration? In my startup.cs I have the token saved in the context.token, but it is null in my controller